# loop through aux and execute a command

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

```
for i in `ps aux | grep /usr/bin/x2goruncommand | awk '{print $1,$13;}'`; do
server=`echo $i | cut -f1`
port=`echo $i | cut -f2`
su -u ${server} -c "DISPLAY:{$port}"
done
```

I am trying to loop through ps and awk.  The loop should only return 5 results but in my attempt above, the result becomes 10.   Essentially my $server variable is returned in one line and then my $port variable gets returned in the following line.  I am trying to run a command in one line that contains both $server and $port variables in one line.

Here is an output of the ps aux command: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm7ad.png

Comment: What is `x2goruncommand`? What does it do with its stdin and stdout?

Comment: it returns all of my x2go sessions and lists out the user and their display port.  Here is an output of it: http://i.imgur.com/USTaNEk.png

Comment: For the 1st line of your `ps aux | grep` output, $1 is "main2" and $13 is "51".  Does that look right?

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful

```
while read s p; 
do 
   echo $s $p; 
done < <(ps aux ...)
```

replace echo with your action.

Comment: Cool, that works.  However on my first loop, the su user -c "DISPLAY=:55 run" is stuck there.  How do I make it not wait and continue on the loop?

Comment: what does `run` do?  Replace with `ls` and retry.  Also are you sure 55 is the right value set for DISPLAY?

Comment: I am essentially executing su -u username -c "DISPLAY:55 javapp"   so the javaapp is starting a java program but it is stuck there until i ctrl-c and then it moves on to the next loop

Comment: Does it ever terminate by itself?  Or, do you want to set it as a background process (`&`)?

Comment: yeah it terminates by itself.  how do I add the &

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a `for` loop to iterate over **lines** -- a `for` loop is used to iterate over **words**. In the first iteration $i="main2", then $i="5114", then $i="0.0", and so on.

You want a `while read` loop

```
ps aux | grep /usr/bin/x2goruncommand | awk '{print $1,$13}' |
while read server port; do
    su -u "$server" -c "DISPLAY:$port"
done
```